# If $s_n$ is an oscillating unbounded sequence and $t^n$ is a bounded sequence then $s_n + t_n$ is oscillating and unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\{s_n\}$be an oscillating sequence and not bounded and $\{t_n\}$ be a bounded sequence.  Then $\{s_n + t_n\}$ is oscillating and unbounded.  True or not?

Since $\{s_n\}$ is unbounded the sequence $\{s_n\}$  does not converge and also does not diverge to $ \infty $ or $- \infty $, then it is similar to $\{(-1)^n n\}$.

For this I can say that the sum $\{s_n + t_n\}$ is oscillating and unbounded but how can I do it for general sequences.

Comment: How are you defining oscillating? What have you tried? Where’s the problem from?

Comment: @Eric   This problem is from "methods of real analysis" by "Richard R Goldberg" (section 2.8)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=plot+Sec%5Bx%5D%2BArcSech%5Bx%5D , does satisfy the ${Sn + Tn}$ conditions?

Comment: I can imagine sequences that are oscillating and diverging and are not similar to yours at all.

Comment: @XZCY but $t_n$ of your problem is not bounded is it?

Comment: @LakshmiPriya $sec^-1(x)$ is bounded in $[0,pi]$

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Show that *either* $s_n$ has a subsequence $A$ which tends to $+\infty$ as well as a subsequence $B$ which tends to $-\infty,$ *or*
$s_n$ has a sequence $C$ going to one of $\pm \infty$ and $s_n$ has a bounded subsequence $D.$ [using oscillating assumption] Then combine each possibility with the fact that $t_n$ is bounded.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I agree and have tried to adjust my hint.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Bounded+ unbounded => unbounded

Unbounded => does not converge to finite

Converges to $\pm\infty$ - bounded => Converges to $\pm \infty$ , so contrapositve:

Oscilatory +bounded=> (not converge to $\pm \infty$)+ bounded => not converge to $\pm \infty$